# How to hide excel gridlines using OpenXML SDK

Tags: c#, excel, hide, openxml, gridlines

Im using OpenXML SDK 2.5 for creating excel file. I want to hide gridlines on created excel files.I was tried creating SheetViews but it completely hide sheet. My pure code as below

```
public static SpreadsheetDocument CreateWorkbook(MemoryStream memoryStream)
    {
        var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

        spreadSheet.AddWorkbookPart();
        spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
        spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();

        var sharedStringTablePart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<SharedStringTablePart>();
        sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable = new SharedStringTable();
        sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Save();

        spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new Sheets();
        spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();

        var workbookStylesPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
        workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet = new Stylesheet();
        workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();

        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return spreadSheet;
    } 

    public static bool AddWorksheet(SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet, string name)
    {
        Sheets sheets = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();

        var worksheetPart = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

        worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

        var sheet = new Sheet()
        {
            Id = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
            SheetId = (uint)(spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.Count() + 1),
            Name = name
        };
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) {
            sheet.Name = string.Format("Sheet{0}", sheet.SheetId);
        }
        sheets.Append(sheet);
        spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();

        return true;
    }
```

After that im creating instance of spreadsheet in memory

```
//Creating like that
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var spreadsheet = CreateWorkbook(memoryStream);       
        AddWorksheet(spreadsheet, null);
//End Filling data
```

After some check i decide to, when you use the column you couldnt hide gridlines. You should only cell for showing data. But that time you couldnt change width property bacause column doesnt extist :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113505/how-to-hide-excel-gridlines-using-openxml-sdk

Comment: I was checked that entity but not work in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. First be sure your pure works properly and generates valid workbook. After that you can apply code:

```
 SheetViews sheetViews = new SheetViews();

 SheetView sheetView = new SheetView(){ ShowGridLines = false, TabSelected = true, ZoomScaleNormal = (UInt32Value)100U, WorkbookViewId = (UInt32Value)0U };
 Selection selection = new Selection(){ ActiveCell = "A1", SequenceOfReferences = new ListValue<StringValue>() { InnerText = "A1" } };

 sheetView.Append(selection);
 sheetViews.Append(sheetView);
 worksheet.Append(sheetViews);
```

Be sure that your sheetViews block is placed before sheetdata, or you will have corrupt document.